How can I prevent Visual Studio Code from opening recently opened files when opening a folder?
When I open a folder that I had previously been working in, files I left open when ending my last session will be automatically opened again.
How can I keep VS Code from re-opening files from a previous session?

just answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/78771658/11107541

In Visual Studio Code:
Go to File > Preferences > Settings, then in the User tab search 'restore windows'.
Set Window: Restore Windows to 'none' and then restart the editor.


Actually, that's my current setting ("window.restoreWindows": "none",). That doesn't do the trick, I'm afraid.
